# Can't pass multidimentional array to php with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Array I am trying to pass:

```
var params = [];
params['request'] = "movies";
params['param'] = [];
params['param']['sortBy'] = "title";
params['param']['sortOrder'] = "asc";
```

Ajax call:

```
return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://192.168.0.100:83/getData.php",
        cache:false,
        data: params,
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data){
            if(data != null){
                            console.log(data);
                        }
```

Problem is that the php script only receives $_POST['request'], params is non-existent.

If I view params array in the console log before the ajax call I see this:

```
[request: "movies", param: Array[0]]
length: 0
param: Array[0]
length: 0
sortBy: "title"
sortOrder: "asc"
__proto__: Array[0]
request: "movies"
__proto__: Array[0]
```

It seems like the problem could be that "param" parameter is not passed because it is seen as empty (it is not, at least before it is passed to ajax call), but why this is happening I have no idea. What am I missing here?

Comment: try sending a json object instead of an array

Comment: @kennypu will try that shortly

Comment: @Toby Allen what exactly do you mean?

Comment: @Toby he didn't mix js and PHP anywhere above.

Comment: Your `params` is actually an object `{}`, not an array `[]` (JavaScript arrays are not like PHP arrays).  Declare it as such. `var params = {};` Same thing with `params['param']`.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Since when do objects have a `length` property?

Comment: @Ian I mean to say that the OP is _using_ `params` like an object (with string properties) rather than using the array `[]` declared.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I knew what you mean. I just didn't think that was the best way of explaining. But I guess it doesn't matter, it's just a comment. You should make an answer though

Comment: Actually I had declared prams with {} notation but I was trying everything out to get it to work, so normally I would use {}. Didn't make any difference in this case anyway...

Comment: [From jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options), _Object must be Key/Value pairs_, so I'm not even certain it will _accept_ a nested object like `params.param`.  Since I've never tried it, I don't know what the result would be.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski, actually your comment with code worked! Please add it as an answer.

Comment: @DominicM Ok, answer added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared `params` as an array `[]` but assigned object properties to it using the `["string"]` notation.  This resulted in empty arrays with additional properties appended to the `Array` object.

Instead, it should have been declared as an object literal, with another object literal nested inside.

```
var params = {
  request: "movies",
  param: {
    sortBy: "title",
    sortOrder: "asc"
  }
};
```

The structure of the `$_POST` should be something like:

```
Array
(
    [request] => movies
    [param] => Array
        (
            [sortBy] => title
            [sortOrder] => asc
        )

)
```

Comment: My problem initially was that I created an object with dot notation and used that for my "param" property. How can I add/append to an object with {} notation?

Comment: @DominicM Same way - via dot notation.  `params.param.newThing = "newvalue"` or via `[]` `params["param"]["newThing"] = "newValue"`, but that is usually used when the property strings are dynamically generated as the result of an expression or variable `params["par" + "am"].newThing = "newValue"`

Comment: The way I had it was: var filters = []; filters.sortBy = "title"; and then: params = {request: "movies", param: filters}; This doesn't work though, can you see why?

Comment: @DominicM Because `filters`, by nature of having string properties like `sortBy` is behaving in your code as an object `{}` not an array `[]`. You need to declare as `var filters = {}; filters.sortBy = "title";`

Answer (score 2):

You could send the data as JSON and decode it in php using `json_decode()`:

```
$.ajax({        
        data: { paramData: JSON.stringify( params),
       /* other ajax options*/

})
```

Then in php receive it with:

```
$params= json_decode($_POST['paramData']); 
echo $params['request']; /* should return "movies" as response*/
```

Include json2.js library for older browsers that don't support JSON methods

EDIT: after a little testing will definitely need to change params to object and params.param to object, Changing `[]` to `{}` will accomplish this:

```
 var params = {};
 params['request'] = "movies";
 params['param'] = {};
 params['param']['sortBy'] = "title";
 params['param']['sortOrder'] = "asc";
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/germk/2/